# dynamic generated html via jQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i m generating dynamic html through jquery, when i am using rowspan than it is not working fine.

Expected output:

[image]

My Current code:

```js
var shopTimeArray = ["10:00:00","10:15:00","10:30:00","10:45:00","11:00:00"];
 var workernames = ["Kapper 1","Kapper 2"];
 var workerids = ['148','196'];
 var workerTimes = [];
 workerTimes['148'] = ["10:00:00","10:15:00","10:30:00","10:45:00","11:00:00"];
 workerTimes['196'] = ["10:00:00","10:15:00","10:30:00","10:45:00","11:00:00"];
 var workerAppointments = [];
 workerAppointments['148'] = ["10:00:00","10:15:00","10:30:00","10:45:00"];
 workerAppointments['196'] = ["10:30:00","10:45:00"];
 var appointmentTime = [];
 appointmentTime['148'] = ["10:00:00"];
 appointmentTime['196'] = ["10:15:00"];
 
 var $elem = $("<table>",{'class':'table table-responsive table-bordered overview-table','border':'1'}); 
 var $thead = $('<thead>',{}).appendTo($elem);
 var $theadTR = $("<tr>",{}).appendTo($thead);
 $("<th>",{'width':'50','html':'Tijd'}).appendTo($theadTR);
 $.each(workernames,function(i)
 {
  $("<th>",{'html':workernames[i]}).appendTo($theadTR); 
 });
 var $tbody = $("<tbody>",{'class':'overview_table_td'}).appendTo($elem);
    $rowspan = 0;
 $.each(shopTimeArray,function(i)
 {
  $tbodyTR = $("<tr>",{}).appendTo($tbody);
  $tbodyTH = $("<th>",{'scope':'row','html':shopTimeArray[i].slice(0,-3)}).appendTo($tbodyTR);
  $.each(workerids,function(j)
  {
   if(typeof(workerTimes[workerids[j]]) != "undefined" && $.inArray(shopTimeArray[i],workerTimes[workerids[j]]) !== -1 )
   {
    //console.log(appointmentTime[workerids[j]]);
    
    if(shopTimeArray[i] == appointmentTime[workerids[j]])
    {
     $.each(workerAppointments[workerids[j]],function(y){
      $rowspan++;
     });
     html = "appointment"+j;
    } else {
     html = '';
    }
    $tbodyTD = $("<td>",{'html':html,'rowspan':$rowspan}).appendTo($tbodyTR);
   }
  });
 });
 $(".overview-table").html($elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview-table">
</div>
```

i tried with the solution like

`if($rowSpan > 0) {
    $rowSpan--;
} else {
   add td
}`

but above code is not working properly.

i want to omit the cells which are in the workerAppointments variable,

currently it is looking wearied,

Looking for help.

Comment: the problem exist on the `$rowspan++;` variable

Comment: How? Can you please describe me?

Comment: You are keep increment the rowspan because of that some case rowspan value is changing into more. check the HTML output you get more clarification